# django-haystack: how update a field of a model index from another model index?

Tags: indexing, solr, django-haystack

i have 3 models.item, auction_items, auction_bids.
item table contains general information.
auction_items table contains auction details like start_time, end_time , start_price if the item is an auction_item.
auction_bids table deals with the bids of each auction_item.

models.py

```
class item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False,blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    ad_type = models.SmallIntegerField(max_length=2,default=1,null=False,blank=True)

class auction_item(models.Model):
    advt = models.ForeignKey(item)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(null=False,blank=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=False,blank=True)
    start_price = models.DecimalField(null=False,max_digits=7,decimal_places=2,blank=True)

class auction_bids(models.Model):
    advt_auction = models.ForeignKey(auction_item)
    bidder_id = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False,blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(null=False,decimal_places=2,max_digits=7,blank=True)
```

search_indexs.py

```
class AuctionIndexes(indexes.SearchIndex,indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

    ad_id=indexes.IntegerField(null=False)
    title = indexes.CharField()
    description = indexes.CharField(null=True)
    start_time= indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='start_time',faceted=True)
    end_time= indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='end_time',faceted=True)
    start_price= indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='start_price')

    current_bid=indexes.IntegerField(null=True)
    def get_model(self):
        return auction_items
    def prepare_ad_id(self,obj):
        return obj.item.pk
    def prepare_title(self, obj):
        return obj.item.title
    def prepare_description(self, obj):
        return obj.item.description
    def prepare_current_bid(self, obj):
        try:
            return int(auction_bids.objects.filter(advt_auction=obj.pk).values('auction_item_id').annotate(current_bid = Max('price'))[0]['current_bid'])
        except:
            return None

class AuctionBidsIndexes(indexes.SearchIndex,indexes.Indexable):
     text=indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=False)
     auction_item = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='auction_item_id')
     bidder_face_id = indexes.CharField(model_attr='bidder_id')
     bid_price = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='price')
     def get_model(self):
         return advt_auction_bids
```

How to get updated `current_bid` when some one bid on that item.
i am using solr as search engine. 
any suggestions please.

Comment: The index needs to be updated every time there is a change.